# Why When I click on Scroll-Up & Scroll-Down Button The page Scrolling stop

Tags: jquery

This Html Code

```html
<div id="scroll-down">
<i  class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-5x wow      bounceIn"       data-wow-delay="2s"></i>
</div>

<div id="scroll-up">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up fa-2x" aria-         hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Why When I click on Scroll-Up & Scroll-Down Button  The page Scrolling stop
This jQuery Code :

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
        $('#scroll-down').click(function(){
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : '632'},800); 
        });
        
        var scrollUp=$('#scroll-up');
        if(st>=1000) {
            scrollUp.fadeIn(600);
        }else{
            scrollUp.fadeOut(600);
        }
        
        scrollUp.click(function(){
           $('html,body').animate({scrollTop : '0'},800); 
        });  
});
```

Comment: Please share your html

Comment: What's your objective?